# What does this output from jar file mean?

Tags: jar

```
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:410)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:173)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1231)
```

I don't get what it means? Are those tools that must be imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the name of a header variable in the Manifest file.

There is a big difference between this:

```
jar cvmf manifest.txt myjar.jar package/*class
```

and this:

```
jar cvfm myjar.jar manifest.txt package/*class
```

The letters `m` and `f` must appear in the same order that the Manifest and myjar appear.

Comment: The only problem now is this: no main manifest attribute, in some.jar

Comment: I'd love to help you solve that. Please open another question with the relevant information and send me a link here (:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952225/no-main-manifest-attribute-in-some-jar